# scroll to content description text

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

Ive been trying to find ways to scroll through gmail's native android app to find specific emails through their content description text

[image: Image Content]

But ive had no luck, i tried using this command here :

```java
String content = "Unread";

driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\""+content+"\").instance(0))");
```

But all this did was scroll past everything.

I need a command that can scroll to find elements by their content description text instead of their display text.

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going for [mobile:shell](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/android-shell/) command instead, the example code would be something like:

```
int startX = 0; //change
int endX = 0;   //these
int startY = 0; //to match your
int endY = 0;   //swipe direction
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("command", "input");
params.put("args", Lists.newArrayList("swipe", startX,
        startY, endX, endY));

while (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@content-desc,'Unread Gogi')]")).size() == 0) {
    driver.executeScript("mobile: shell", params);
}
```

Alternative option is using  [SwipeWhileNotFound](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/SwipeWhileNotFound) command available via [SeeTest Appium Extensions](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/SeeTest+-+Appium+Extension):

```
seetest.swipeWhileNotFound("Down", 0, 2000, "NATIVE", "seetest.swipeWhileNotFound("Down", 0, 2000, "NATIVE", "xpath=//*[contains(@content-desc,'Unread Gogi')]", 0, 1000, 5, true)", 0, 1000, 5, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TouchAction` instead, and I tried to use another `locator`.

This is the locator I mean :

```
By.xpath -> //*[contains(@content-desc,'Unread')]
```

And I try to get the value of `x` `y` of the locator, the bellow code is assumed to want to scroll to the first locator.

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@content-desc,'Unread')]")).size()>0) {
    //the first element contains Unread
    WebElement elemnt = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@content-desc,'Unread')]")).get(0);

    //get x y
    int x = elemnt.getLocation().getX();
    int y = elemnt.getLocation().getY();

    //try to move
    TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
    action.press(x, y).moveTo(x+50, y).release().perform();

    //here you can click the element
    elemnt.click();
}
```

Hope this helps.